# Pharo / Squeak environment with dual screens

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, visualworks

I was just wondering if there is a way to work with multiple screens in Pharo or Squeak. I am just switching from VisualWorks to Pharo and am really missing this feature. I am used to having my workspace / transcript on one and my browsers on the other.

Thanks,
Henrik

Comment: What do you think is the problem? Other than it being a bit slow on the refresh, I've happily spanned a pair of 21" widescreens.

Comment: I think he means multiple windows(?). In that case: no can do. But as Frank says, simply scale the environment window and then you can place your browser / workspace anywhere you like.

Comment: So what you mean is simply make the main windows big enough to cover both screen areas? It works, but is not a very nice solution. Either two main windows or no main window (like VW) would be better I think.

Comment: Yes, spanning single window is not really a solution. Doesn't works if your monitors having different resolution. And this very common case.

Comment: Spanning also doesn't work if the two monitors are at differing physical heights.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so for now the answer is:

To use Pharo/Squeak on multiple screens either:

- span the main window over both of them;
- or launch multiple images.

Right now no option of having morph as a separate window is available.

Answer (score 2):

The basics of support for multiple windows has been in Squeak since 2005 or so. It just needs one of the people that spent years requesting this capability and assuring us that it was utterly crucial to make/find the time and oomph to do the higher level work.

Comment: I'd do the grunt work, if someone would point me to where the basics reside in Squeak.

Comment: Just spotted this; for the record, take look at the 'Graphics-External-Ffenestri' category in a Browser. In particular the DisplayHostWindow class example.

Comment: I'll start there tgen

Answer (score 1):

You can now with [GToolkit](https://gtoolkit.com). Also the new Gtk backend for Pharo supports it